# 'The property 'Claims' on type 'Users' is not a navigation property.' when trying to login using Owin

Tags: c#, authentication, owin, claims-based-identity

I have the following error when I try to Login using user name (email) and password.

```
The property 'Claims' on type 'Users' is not a navigation property. The Reference and Collection methods can only be used with navigation properties. Use the Property or ComplexProperty method.
```

However I don't understand where this error is coming from since I'm able to successfully register a person without having anything remotely to claims in my own database.

The code fails the moment I try to do userManager.FindAsync.

```
        try
        {
            var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

            Users user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }

            var oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            var cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            var properties = CreateProperties(user.Email);
            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);

            context.Validated(ticket);
            context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Could not find client data due to following error: {0}", ex));
        }
```

My Users Class (which is created from my sql database):

```
    public partial class Users
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public override string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public override string UserName { get; set; }
    }
```

Separate file:

```
public partial class Users : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<Users> manager, string authenticationType)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Where am I overlooking something that could cause the error that I'm receiving?

Registration works fine:

```
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        try {
            var email = model.Email;
            var password = model.Password;
            var hashedPassword = PasswordHash.HashPassword(password);

            Users user = new Users
            {
                UserName = email,
                Email = email,
                PasswordHash = hashedPassword,
                Password = hashedPassword
            };

            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, hashedPassword);

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                return GetErrorResult(result);
            }

            return Ok();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Error while trying to Register: ", ex));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got it to work based on the demo I found on http://bitoftech.net/, so I used the demo code as basis instead and migrated everything step by step. Now my authentication works.

My suggestion for future developers. Use the demo immediately as basis. It works like a charm.

I did notice the demo did set claims and creates a claims table.